# Selecting the Variant ID server side in Google Optimize

Tags: google-optimize

I'm trying to use **Google Optimize** at the server side in a `aspx` page. This [document](https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/experiments) says the variant should be selected randomly:

`$variationId = rand(0, 2);`

Is there way to get the `$variationId` from the **Google Optimize** instead of the app selecting randomly? If the traffic is split for two variants, the next `$variationId` that the app should use should be what **Google Optimize** provides and not the app provides.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood from the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/experiments), Is that you need to manually do the targetting yourself. Soo, To answer your question I don't think it's possible to get the $variationId form optimize itself.

Possible Solutions:

Use the google analytics ID stored in the cookie (_ga) to uniquely identify your target audience and use a back-end implementation to keep track of GA ID and split the audience among the original & the variants.

Hope this points you in the right direction

Cheers!